# invalidOperationExceptions was unhandled in entity framwork

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am new to Entity Framework. I create a stored procedure and I added it to my `.edmx` file but problem is that when I call this, it causes an exception

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to a nullable 'System.Boolean' type is not valid.

This is in `.edmx` file

```
public ObjectResult<Nullable<global::System.Boolean>> uspLoginWindowsApp(global::System.String userName, global::System.String password, global::System.String userType, ObjectParameter result)
{
        ObjectParameter userNameParameter;
        if (userName != null)
        {
            userNameParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserName", userName);
        }
        else
        {
            userNameParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserName", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        ObjectParameter passwordParameter;
        if (password != null)
        {
            passwordParameter = new ObjectParameter("Password", password);
        }
        else
        {
            passwordParameter = new ObjectParameter("Password", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        ObjectParameter userTypeParameter;
        if (userType != null)
        {
            userTypeParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserType", userType);
        }
        else
        {
            userTypeParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserType", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        return base.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<global::System.Boolean>>("uspLoginWindowsApp", userNameParameter, passwordParameter, userTypeParameter, result);
    }
```

This part is my code where I am calling the function:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (_context == null)
            _context = new ATSdbEntities();

        ObjectParameter userTypeParameter = new ObjectParameter("result", false);

        // This line here is causing the error
        Boolean userExists = (Boolean)_context.uspLoginWindowsApp(txtLogin.Text.Trim(), txtPswd.Text.Trim(), cmbType.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), userTypeParameter).Single();

        if (userExists)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Credential ");
        }
    }
```

my stored procedure are below are looking like below

```
    ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspLoginWindowsApp]
@UserName varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@UserType varchar(50),
@result bit output
```

Comment: @marc_s my stored procedure structure a have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know yet what your stored procedure really looks like - assuming it just takes three `varchar` parameters and returns the result as an `OUTPUT` parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspLoginWindowsApp
    @UserName VARCHAR(50),
    @Password VARCHAR(50),
    @UserType VARCHAR(50),
    @Result BIT OUTPUT
```

I then added this stored procedure to a new `.edmx` in Visual Studio 2012 and created the function import.

When I call this stored procedure, what I get back from Entity Framework is the return value of the stored procedure (always an `INT`), and the result you're looking for will be in the `ObjectParameter` that you pass in as the last parameter to your call:

```
// this parameter will hold the @Result value
ObjectParameter resultParam = new ObjectParameter("result", false);

int returnStatus = ctx.uspLoginWindowsApp("marc_s", "testpwd", "normal", resultParam);

// get the value of the @Result OUTPUT Parameter
bool userExists = resultParam.Value;
```

and now you have your result - whether or not the user exists.

Comment: my stored procedure @result bit output means true or false .